# HTML duplicate form without ID conflicts

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form set up that is displayed as a jquery UI dialog. Many of the elements have javascript associated with them that manipulate other objects on the form. So, for example, I might have something like the following:

```
$('#empNumber').change(function(){
    $.getJSON('getEmpInfo',{...},function(response){
        $('#empName').val(response.empName);
        ...
    }
})
```

Which would, of course, populate the employee name (and other info) when an employee number is entered.

I now want to display this same form in a second location on the page (visually it's a different tab than where the dialog is accessed from, but HTML wise it's simply a different div), as child of a different form rather than by itself.

My first thought, given that everything is template, was to simply include this form in the second location where I needed it. But now I have a problem: all the id's are duplicated. Which is not only bad practice, it breaks things like the code above.

So, basically, I need two copies of my form and associated javascript. One to display as a stand-alone dialog, and a second to display as a child of another object. I could, of course, change all the ID's, but then I'd have to have two copies of the code as well, which would be annoying at best. So what's the best solution?

Comment: use `class` instead of `id` attribute. but still you need to take care some code regarding submit and validation which depends on how it is designed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just shouldn't use IDs if you're expecting to have more than one of them on the same page. Use classes instead:

```
$('.empNumber').change(function(){
    $.getJSON('getEmpInfo',{...},function(response){
        $('.empName').val(response.empName);
        ...
    }
})
```

Also, you'll need to modify your code so that all your selectors are self-contained and can't cause issues in other parts of the page. Usually I would do something like this:

```
var initializeForm = function($el) {
  // all selectors will be within the `.myFirstForm` or `.mySecondForm` wrappers
  $el.find('.empNumber').change(function(){
      $.getJSON('getEmpInfo',{...},function(response){
          $el.find('.empName').val(response.empName);
          ...
      }
  });
}

initializeForm($('#myFirstForm'));
initializeForm($('#mySecondForm'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have them inside a div which has a unique id, and then using css selectors for descendants, select them uniquely.

Say I have

```
<div id="form1"> 
<input class = "empNumber" />
</div>
<div id="form2"> 
<input class = "empNumber" />
</div>
```

and then use `$('#form1 .empNumber')` to select the first one.

Comment: Makes sense, but then how do I prevent needing two copies of the javascript to populate the "correct" one?

Comment: Use a variable for the string as well? Concatenate the first part using a variable. It depends on the complete use case.

Comment: The use case is that this form can get filled out from either of two different locations (tabs, visually) on the same page. Depending on which tab the user is currently viewing, they will either need to fill out just this form, or this form plus some additional data. So I display either the dialog of this form, or the additional form with this form embedded in the div. Does that help?

Comment: ids have to be unique for it to be valid HTML, so this wouldn't validate, and could conceivably confuse things like screen readers or other accessiblity methods and testing frameworks.

Comment: agreed @blm, the inputs can be replaced with classes and then this logic can be applied then. Editing my answer